# Can't add custom filter to logger

Tags: python, logging

I have the following filter to add colors:

```
class CustomFilter(logging.Filter):

    COLOR = {
        "DEBUG": "GREEN",
        "INFO": "GREEN",
        "WARNING": "YELLOW",
        "ERROR": "RED",
        "CRITICAL": "RED",
    }

    def filter(self, record):
        record.color = CustomFilter.COLOR[record.levelname]
        return True
```

applied to logger with format `"%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(name)s - (%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"`

So it should be something like that:

```
2020-07-25 22:45:17,178 - [DEBUG] - [GREEN] - __main__ - (main.py).<module>(52) - message
```

but I get:

```
2022-03-10 09:47:03,865 - [INFO] - fastapi - (check_service.py).check_service_status(68) - msg
```

I was trying to add filter to Handlers (there are file and stream ones) and to logger itself, but result is the same. How I should fix it?

The whole code:

```
import logging
from core.config import settings
import sys


class CustomFilter(logging.Filter):

    COLOR = {
        "DEBUG": "GREEN",
        "INFO": "GREEN",
        "WARNING": "YELLOW",
        "ERROR": "RED",
        "CRITICAL": "RED",
    }

    def filter(self, record):
        record.color = CustomFilter.COLOR[record.levelname]
        return True


logFormatter = logging.Formatter(settings.conf["log_config"]["Format"])
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(settings.conf["log_config"]["Path"])
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
fileHandler.addFilter(CustomFilter())

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
consoleHandler.addFilter(CustomFilter())

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(CustomFilter())
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
logger.setLevel(settings.conf["log_config"]["Level"])
```